# Plotly get legend visible status

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

Is it possible to get the current status of the legend which line is shown or hidden?

```
document.querySelectorAll(`[id^="plot_${id}"]`).forEach((plot: any) => {
 console.log(plot._fullLayout)
})
```

Comment: You could check the legend via `document.getElementsByClassName('traces')` and `[0].style.opacity === '1'` would show if the first trace is shown or hidden.

Comment: Plotly do not support this.

Comment: Plotly is not directly supporting it but you can take advantage of d3 which is used to build the plots.